# Control Barcode Scanner Programmatically using C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, pos-for-.net

I've been thinking whats the best way to handle a barcode scanner via code. The thing is, I have 3 different pattern of barcodes in one window/dialog. before I put these barcodes in the right field i should be able to handle the barcode scanner programmatically. similar to how we handle others devices via serial port. But my barcode scanner is detected as HID instead of COM. what should i do? I've tried the **Point of Service for .Net** but it doesn't recognized the scanner. Point of Service always returns "Simulator devices" and not the actual devices installed on the PC.

I understand that my barcode scanner detects as a keyboard. but the thing is that I want to control it programmatically to place the right barcodes in the right fields.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Since you knew it's like keyboard, so what do you mean by control it programmatically? However for this, start thinking about handling serial port. .Net has built-in classes for this.

Comment: to place the right barcodes in the right fields, because I have 3 different barcodes in one window/dialog.

Comment: I already tried using a serial port, but my barcode scanner is not detected as serial port. instead it is listed in the HID section

Comment: So just to make sure I understood: when user read a barcode, your application should capture the text, identity to which category it belongs, and put it somewhere.

Comment: Intercept the keyboard input, recognize the pattern of each barcode, and send them to respective text field accordingly?

Comment: There is an HID Library in NuGet, you may go through it and find your needs. the code is available on https://github.com/mikeobrien/HidLibrary make sure you check the wiki of it or any available documentation.